# android - handle virtual keyboard enter key behaviour

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I have five edittext in my layout. by default when i click on any of the edittext the virtual keyboard shows like following

[image]

Is it possible to modify the behavior of enter key ? I want when the key pressed the focus should be transferred to next edit text. Keyboard should look like

[image: notice the change in enter key and also suggestions are disabled]

notice the change in enter key and also suggestions are disabled. Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable text suggestions, add the following parameter to your `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    (…)
/>
```

And to go to the next field upon pressing "enter" add the ID of the next field on the following parameter:

```
<EditText
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/nextEditTextId"
    (…)
/>
```

Details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html).

Hope it helps!